# Arduino Uno with Camera and LCD

Tags: lcd

I would like to ask you if I can display real time view from Camera in Arduino Uno with LCD.

**I have that components:**

- Camera OV7670 VGA 0.3 MPX
- LCD TFT 2.4 SPI ILI9341
- Arduino Uno R3

On a website: arducam.com there are used another components. I bought that parts because in a documentation in auction was that is compatible with Arduino.
I see that in Arduino UNO is not so much pins.

Could somebody help me to resolve this challenge?

Regards

Comment: That article says you need an ArduCAM CC3200 Uno - not an Arduino Uno.

Comment: This is like hauling building materials in a SmartCar.  Maybe you can get a still picture from the camera to the LCD.  But I can not imagine it being very fast if at all possible.  And you certainly could not do anything fancy.  For example, if the camera image needed to be transposed there is not enough memory in a Uno to hold the image in order to operate on it.  It would be much easier to use a more powerful platform.

Comment: Please add links to the products, schematics, board pin layout, etc. You should at least do the ground work before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

The camera outputs a JPEG image. To display that on the TFT screen it is necessary to decompress that JPEG image and send the raw 16-bit (RGB565) colour information to the screen.

The Arduino doesn't have enough memory to do the job.

I wrote an absolute minimal JPEG decompressor a while back. It uses the absolute minimum memory possible (it operates on one macroblock at a time), and still requires around 100KB. That's 50x more than the Arduino Uno has.

Also on a 200MHz, 32-bit chip with FPU it takes about a minute to decompress a 320x240 pixel image. I can't even begin to imagine how many days that would take on a little Arduino Uno even if it did have enough memory to do the job...

As has been suggested, you need a more powerful board. And if you're going that route you may as well drop the useless OV7670 and get a Raspberry Pi with a proper Pi Camera module (or at least a USB webcam).

Comment: Useless? Why the hate?

Comment: Because it's a pretty pointless device. Certainly in the context of Arduino. You can't do anything with it other than copy the data to somewhere else, such as an SD card, so you may as well just hack a real digital camera (or use one with an external shutter trigger) and get some reasonable quality pictures out of it.

Comment: You're mostly right...even an SD card is only useful if you want to take pics every once in a while and definitely not for moving pictures. Slight correction though: this camera doesn't output JPEG; I think its RGB565 and YUV422 and small resolutions (up to QCIF) are supported.